# Just installed the Jenkins. What to do with Apache SSL Proxy Settings?

Tags: jenkins

Just installed the Jenkins.

First I see this page:

[image: Jenkins Dashboard]

And then made a Agent.

Now see this page:

[image: So proxy setting is wrong]

What is wrong with Apache SSL Proxy Settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it work with my own efforts. SSL Proxy settings must be set like below:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   # .. some configuration here

   <Location />
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Location>

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

   <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
   </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/ nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse  /  http://subdomain.yuordomain.com/
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"

</VirtualHost>
```

Documentation will found from internet for this all. Thanks any way nobody else than me did not answered for this question.